# Image User Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I have created an interface called user with an email property, password and photo url. When I load it in the ngOnInit() the value user (object) photo url says src = (unknown). **I want to show the associated image (storage - when I register / create the user) on the header**

```
//user.class.ts
export class User {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  photoUrl: string;
}

//header.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/service/auth.service';
import { User } from 'src/app/share/user.class';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  user: User = new User();

  constructor(
    private router: Router, 
    private auth:AngularFireAuth, 
    private authSvc:AuthService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authSvc.isAuth().subscribe(user => {
      if(user) {
        this.user.photoUrl = user.photoUrl;
        console.log(this.user.photoUrl);
      }
    })
  }

  //auth.service.ts
  isAuth(user: User) {
   return this.auth.authState.pipe(map(user => user));
  }

  //header.html
  <ion-avatar>
    <img src="{{user.photoUrl}}" />
  </ion-avatar>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a web app with angular and firebase.
fUser is the user from firebase, and User is my interface

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth'

import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators'

import { User as fUser } from 'firebase'
import { User } from '@models/User'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-test',
    templateUrl: './test.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

    public user$: Observable<fUser> = this.auth.user
    public currentUser: User

    constructor(
        private auth: AngularFireAuth
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.user$.pipe(first()).toPromise().then(user => {
            this.currentUser = user as User
        })
    }
}
```